# ログインIDとして使うメールアドレスは Case Sensitive / Insensitive?

Tags: security, mail, webapi

メールアドレスは大文字小文字を区別しないで運用される慣習のようです。一方で、ここ StackExchange を含めてメールアドレスをログイン ID として使うサービスは多数あります。

Q. ログイン ID としてメールアドレスをユーザーが POST してきたとき、これを受け取るサービス側はログイン ID としてのメールアドレスの大文字小文字を区別すべきでしょうか、しないべきでしょうか？

i.e;
`joHndOe@exAmple.Com` というメールアドレスでユーザー登録がなされたとき

- `johndoe@example.com` でログインすることは是か非か
- `JOHNDOE@EXAMPLE.COM` でログインすることは是か非か

ちなみに ja.stackoverflow.com は大文字小文字を区別しない方法の様子。

Comment: 運用側のポリシー次第だと思いますが。ログインIDをメールアドレスに限定している意味はありますか？本質はメールアドレスの大文字小文字区別の規定と実際の違いの話じゃないですか？

Comment: 現在稼働しているメールというシステムにおいて大文字小文字を区別しないという現状についてどうこう言う気はないです（現状を覆せないので）。ログインIDとしてメールアドレスを使う場合に話を限定したいです。ログインIDとしてメールアドレスでないものを使う場合は話が発散するので今回のこの発言では除外。まあポリシー次第と言われればそれで終わりなのですが。

Answer (score 0):

ログインIDが、純粋にログインのためだけに使われるのであれば、それはログインチェックを厳しくしたいか緩くしたいかだけの話で運用側のポリシー次第でしょう。

問題はそこではなくて、多くの場合ログインIDはそのままユーザー識別子として使われることでは？
そうなると、ログイン時のチェックはともかく、内部的な比較としては大文字小文字は区別すべきではないと思います。
理由はユーザーの取り違えや成りすましの対策のためです

ログイン以外で大文字小文字を区別しないものを、ログイン時だけ区別するというのはユーザーフレンドリーではないとは思います。
なので個人的にはなしだとは思います

公開するメールアドレスとして小文字で公開し、ログインＩＤを大文字で設定するとかすれば、不正ログイン対策としては有効かもしれませんが